# CentOS6.5 iptables rule not working after some minutes

Tags: linux, centos

I want to redirect port 80 to 8080 using iptables. I did it using these commands:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j  REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
/etc/init.d/iptables save
/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

After running these command it works well but after some minutes, the redirection does not work and I have to restart the iptables service and then it works again.

Please let me know what is wrong with these commands.

Thanks

Comment: What is the output when this stops working?

Comment: When the redirect stops working, does `iptables -t nat -L` show that the redirect rule is still in place?